# Proof, that $n! < m!$ when $n<m$

Tags: proof-writing, factorial

For another proof I just assumed, that  $n! < m! \;$ for all $\;n<m$. And I mean it is kind of obvious that this is the case, but then again I should be able to prove it. However I have no idea where to start there. Can someone give me a hint (or the solution)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define $n!$?

Comment: It's false for $n=0\land m=1$, but other than that it's true. You could observe that $m!=n!\times\prod_{j=n+1}^m j$.

Comment: $m!/n! = (n+1)(n+2)\cdots m$

Comment: @AnotherUser the book I'm working with defined it as $1 \cdot 2 \cdots n$, but I'm happy to work with another definition if you prefer another.

Comment: But then $m!=n!\times(n+1)\times(n+2)\times\cdots\times m>n!$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because $n!$ has only one definition and the inequality is obvious as OP already stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n<m$,
$$n!=1\times2\times...\times(n-1)\times n\qquad\qquad\text{and,}$$
$$m!=\underbrace{1\times2\times...\times (n-1)\times n}_{n!}\times (n+1)\times...\times(m-1)\times m\\=n!\times(n+1)\times...\times(m-1)\times m.$$

Hence,$$\frac{m!}{n!}=(n+1)\times...\times(m-1)\times m>1\Rightarrow m!>n!$$
since, $m>n\ge1\Rightarrow(n+1),...,(m-1)>1$.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I'm so stupid sometimes x)

Comment: @Hebol don't worry been there :p when you can't figure anything write down the definition clearly.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint*: Notice that if $n<m$, then $$m!=m\cdot (m-1)\cdot(m-2)\ldots\cdot n\cdot(n-1)\ldots \cdot1 = m\cdot (m-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot n!$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice!